# Visual Studio 2017 (Professional) Offline Update Layout Is Missing Packages

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017, updates, offline

A while ago I've created a offline install layout for VS2017 Professional (Version 15.5) - this is the base for a couple of dev-hosts at work.

Now we want to upgrade to VS2017 - version 15.8 - so I've createad a 1:1 copy of the existing layout and ran

```
vs_Professional.exe --layout <path_to_layout>
```

which ran for a while and updated ?all? packages in the layout.

**doing a clean install with this updated layout does work well, however - when using this layout to update one of the hosts that have version 15.5 installed the update procedure fails with exit code "1".**

sidenote: VS actually states that it's now 15.8.4 - but it exits with an error code .. so ..?

the command I use for install/update is
(drop the "update" for the clean installation)

```
vs_Professional.exe update --passive --norestart --wait --productkey $productKey --nocache --noUpdateInstaller --noWeb
```

using collect.exe there is a state.errors.json file which states that a couple of packages are missing on the layout path...

NOTE: I need to have all required packages available in the offline layout - because some of the PCs do not have internet access (despite we've got the requirement that those vs-setups need to be identical...)

I've tried to reach out to Microsoft Support but didn't hear back from the till now. - anyone else having this issue / was able to solve it?

Comment: re-posted at msdn forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/16195801-027c-4449-8003-6b84411b664d/visual-studio-2017-professional-offline-update-layout-is-missing-packages?forum=vsprofessionalandenterprisede

Comment: Please use the --verify parameter to perform verification on this offline installer, check this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#how-to-verify-a-layout and use the --fix once there have missing files. When you upgrade your installed vs using this offline installer, make sure the offline folder is the same as the previous one that used to install the initial vs. For example, you use offline folder d:\vs2017offline to install, it will still search the resources in the same folder d:\vs2017offline to upgrade.

Comment: thanks for the response, in fact I need the possibility to choose between the old and the new version when doing a clean install - how can this be achieved if an update always points back to the original location? (always creating a completely separate layout for each version seems like an overkill)

Comment: We can use update the offline installer follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#how-to-update-a-network-layout on your computer that have the internet network, then copy the contents and paste into the original location on your offline computer.

Comment: yes, I've done that - but how can I explicitly choose to install the old version once I've updated the layout? - this is why I copied the layout folder in the first place - I need that ability to choose which version to install..

Comment: As far as I know we cannot meet this requirement, if we do not directly upgrade from the previous folder, we need to remove the installed VS then install it from different offline folders for different versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update process of an MSFT Visual Studio offline layout seems to be rather buggy, yet there is at least 1 way which seems to work consistently:

**always, always, always note the exact parameters you've used to create a offline layout! (all packages, included extras, language - the exact command line(s) you've used!**

### 1: create a copy of the existing offline layout

You'll want to do that if you need to be able to keep using the old layout version for new installs, as Sara Liu pointed out in the comments of the original question. (installing a 'older version' of an updated layout is not supported.)

Also, in case something breaks during the update - you don't loose anything ;-)

### 2: update the duplicated offline layout

```
vs_Professional.exe --layout <path_to_layout>
```

after this finished you should be able to install the new VisualStudio version from this updated layout, yet upgrading a older version will probably fail.

To resolve this, MSFT gives you the

```
vs_Professional.exe --verify
vs_Professional.exe --fix
```

tools you can throw at your layout - but don't expect it to work - it never figured out what packages have been missing in my scenarios.

if you follow point 3, you'll also be able to upgrade existing installations.

### 3: create a new layout with the same parameters as the original one and copy the files over the updated layout

it's quite weird I know - but this has given me the missing packages for the upgrade scenario all the time. just don't forget to fix your ChannelManifest.json afterwards.

Comment: also works for vs2019 (upgrading a offline layout 16.7.6 to 16.9.4)

Comment: unfortunately this is STILL the way to go when upgrading 16.9 to 16.11, let's hope msft does a better job with vs2022 -_-