# New Version of Visual Studio Installer breaks Offline Layout, causing ExitCode 5008

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-installer

We’re using a offline-layout for VS2022 Professional LTSC, 17.8.5 and it has been working until yesterday.

Hosts updating from an earlier verison using the switches

```
\\path-to-layout\\vs_professional.exe update --passive --norestart --wait --nocache --noWeb --installPath C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional
```

have been able to update, along with the update vs_installer has been updated to version `3.8.2122.285739328`.

up until yesterday, you could see the success in dd_bootstrapper_*.log in %temp% :

```
...
[4044:0008] [2024-02-13T18:37:27] Comparing client version '3.8.2122.285739328' to autoSelfUpdateMinVersion '3.8.2122.285739328'
...
[4044:0008] [2024-02-13T18:37:27] VS setup process C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\setup.exe started. All done.
[4044:0008] [2024-02-13T18:37:27] Waiting for setup process to complete...
[4044:000a] [2024-02-13T18:37:32] Pipe disconnected.
[4044:0008] [2024-02-13T18:37:32] VS setup process exited with code 0
[4044:0008] [2024-02-13T18:37:32] Bootstrapper Successfully completed.
```

As of today, the same command fails, vs_professional exists with ‘5008’ and dd_bootstrapper_*.log in %temp% cotains the following lines.

```
...
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:21] Latest installer feed version 3.9.2164.285805670 greater than self update min version: 3.8.2122.285739328
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:21] Comparing client version '3.8.2122.285739328' to autoSelfUpdateMinVersion '3.9.2164.285805670'
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:21] Using Offline package: \\path-to-layout\vs_installer.opc
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:21] Saving Certificates to layout folder
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:22] Package signature verification returned Success for path:\\path-to-layout\vs_installer.opc
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:22] Current OptIn value is 1
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:22] Extracting file 'vs_installer.version.json' from package stream.
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:22] File found 'vs_installer.version.json' in package stream.
[0700:0022] [2024-02-14T07:43:23] Download requested: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/36f29b27-1fec-4bff-b8ed-243475a41412/85663fdde2205b96d817390340144a08/latestinstaller.json
[0700:0023] [2024-02-14T07:43:23] Attempting download 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/36f29b27-1fec-4bff-b8ed-243475a41412/85663fdde2205b96d817390340144a08/latestinstaller.json' using engine 'WebClient'
[0700:0023] [2024-02-14T07:43:23] ManifestVerifier Result: Success
[0700:0023] [2024-02-14T07:43:23] Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/36f29b27-1fec-4bff-b8ed-243475a41412/85663fdde2205b96d817390340144a08/latestinstaller.json' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:23] ManifestVerifier Result: Success
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:23] Latest installer feed version 3.9.2164.285805670 greater than self update min version: 3.8.2122.285739328
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:23] Comparing client version '3.8.2122.285739328' to autoSelfUpdateMinVersion '3.9.2164.285805670'
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:23] Warning: Unexpected Installer Version. Starting version='3.8.2122.285739328' Launching version='3.8.2122.285739328'  MinVersion='3.8.2122.285739328'.
[0700:0007] [2024-02-14T07:43:23] Bootstrapper failed with known error.
```

This 'known error' causes vs_professional to exit with exit code 5008.

Following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), one might guess that `vs_professional.exe --quiet --update --offline` before doing the actual upgrade might update vs_installer to the latest version before:

Does not work.
(same error in vs_bootstrapper log)

Sidenote: there are some inconsistencies in the offline-layout maintenance instructions (i.e. --offline is not documented, --noUpdateInstaller does behave differently when there is a internet connection available/if there is not)

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-minimal-layout?view=vs-2022
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: note that I've put this question/answer on the Visual Studio Developer Community Forum but also posted here because I think SO has better reach and doesn't break links like Microsoft does. - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Installer-breaks-Offline-L/10584412

Answer (score 2):

I've been in touch with Microsoft Support and indeed, vs_installer version ‘3.9.2164.285805670’ has been releases which causes the update from the offline-layout to fail.

tldr;-

It seems that you can work around this issue by grabbing the new version of vs_installer from https://aka.ms/vs/install/latest/installer and install it before running the upgrade from the offline layout.

```
\\path-to-layout\vs_professional.exe --quiet --update --offline path_to\vs_installer.opc
```

When using offline-layouts this is normally not something you'd want to do, but I've basically already given up on trying to make some sense of the Visual Studio Installer ecosystem. I've been rambling about this and similar issues [vs2019 - here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259223/visual-studio-2019-offline-layout-update-ignoring-noupdateinstaller) and [vs2017 - here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428110/visual-studio-2017-professional-offline-update-layout-is-missing-packages).

At this point I suggest to do the following:

- when you're in an offline/air-gapped environment, great! - don't worry about the installer and go with `-noUpdateInstaller`
- when your're installing/updating from an offline layout and still want the updates to succeed most of the time - manually ensure to update to the latest version of vs_installer prior to invoking the VS bootstrapper.

I.e. when you're managing your deployments with Chocolatey packages, one could easy pop a tiny PowerShell-script up front:

```
  $tempFile = Join-Path $env:TEMP 'vs_installer.opc'
  if (Test-Path $tempFile) { Remove-Item $tempFile -Force }

  $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
  Invoke-WebRequest -URI 'https://aka.ms/vs/install/latest/installer' -OutFile $tempFile -ErrorAction Stop -UseBasicParsing

  $vsInstallerUpdateParams = @{
    ExeToRun   = '\\path-to-layout\vs_professional.exe'
    Statements = "--quiet --wait --update --offline $tempFile"
  }
  Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin @vsInstallerUpdateParams
```

~ hope this might help someone ~